# Get full drive path for fopen() function in php

Tags: php

I have a CSV file ( sample.csv ), put in my flashdisk ( drive L: ). I read those file to update my database. I try to run it on localhost, everything works fine.But if the script I uploaded to the internet server, the script is always error. The server can not recognize the disk drive where I put the file (disk drive L:). Here is my first script before :

```
if (isset($_POST['upload1'])) {
$allowed_ext = array('csv');
$file_name  = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_ext   = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
$file_path  = realpath($_FILES['file']['name']);
if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === true){
$handle = fopen($file_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'], "r" );  
while (! feof($handle)) {
$import=fgets($handle);
}
fclose($handle);
}
}
```

Because those script is not going well, then I try to add a few lines to determine the location of faults, this is the complete script:

```
if (isset($_POST['upload1'])) {
$allowed_ext = array('csv');
$file_name  = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_ext   = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
$file_path  = realpath($_FILES['file']['name']);
if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === true){
if (!@fopen($file_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'], 'r')) {
echo $file_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
var_dump($php_errormsg);
}else{
$handle = fopen($file_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'], "r" );  
while (! feof($handle)) {
$import=fgets($handle);
}
fclose($handle);
}
}
}
```

From the second script, I know that disk drives are not known because it gives the following message:  **/SAMPLE.CSV NULL**

**/SAMPLE.CSV** is the output of  echo $file_path.'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];

**NULL** is the output off var_dump($php_errormsg);

My question is how the script for the program to read the csv file from the drive L: ( **L:/SAMPLE.CSV** )
Thank you for any advices.

Comment: [php file upload](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php), use `tmp_name` insteadof `name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the CSV to your server

```
if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) === true)
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '/your/directory/yourfile.csv');
}
```

Then loop through the CSV as requested

```
if (($handle = fopen("/your/directory/yourfile.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $fieldOne = trim($data[0]);
        $fieldTwo = trim($data[1]);
        $fieldThree = trim($data[3]);

        // do stuff
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

After you have done what you need to with you CSV rows then delete the file

```
unlink('/your/directory/yourfile.csv');
```

Comment: Thank you for respons my q. I use those program to read from removable disk ( eg. flash disk ). The csv file must be read each line for my purpose. Then the program must know where the csv file is placed. Not in certainly drive name. if different computers can generate a different drive name too.
so the main issue is how the program can record the drive location of the csv file (after browse in a certain drive and select the file). so I can not use the command: '/your/directory/yourfile.csv'

Comment: Well if you want to read the CSV file you could first use this function to move the file onto your server in a tmp file for example. Then you can use PHP to read the file like you were doing and read the lines of the CSV. Afterwards delete the file using unlink(). Updated my answer above